# Was to do sth v. would do sth

Tags: grammar, tense

> This discovery **was to have** a major effect on the treatment of heart disease.

This sentence is from the [Longman dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/was-were-to-do-something). While I understand how it differs from "the discovery **had** [...]" (there was a discovery first, and then later an impact, not a discovery and an impact at the same time), I don't understand how it differs from "the discovery **would have** [...]". Help me out, please

Comment: There's not much difference in meaning. "Was to have" could be understood as "was going to have," with the "going" omitted.

Comment: @andybonner ...but not necessarily having, is that what you mean?

Comment: Right; it's a future-tense phrase in the midst of a past-tense sentence. A similar scenario: Present tense: Scrooge is at home. Is is **to be** [i.e., "going to be"] visited by three ghosts. Past tense. Scrooge was at home. He **was to be** [was going to be] visited by three ghosts. We're just talking about something that *had not* happened yet at the time of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: You could say that it's short for 'was destined to have'. We know, with hindsight, that that is what would happen in the future.