# usage of "be also to do in"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

"Scots communities appear to have made a major contribution to the development of educational institutions everywhere in the colonies of settlement, as Scottish foreign missions **were also to do in** India,Africa, and elsewhere."

I understand the overall meaning of this sentence, but I'm confused by the phrase "as ... were also to do in...". Could someone clarify the structure and the usage of this phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text we're looking at is ***were [also] to do***, which is a "Future in the Past" construction.

Preposition ***in*** refers ***India, Africa, etc.,*** and is not relevant to this question. The word ***also*** is also syntactically irrelevant - if we remove ***also*** and append ***too*** or ***as well*** to the end of the sentence, the meaning doesn't change.

Note that there's no real difference in meaning if we replace ***were to do*** with Simple Past ***did***. But the more roundabout phrasing tends to shift the focus back to the *situation* in the past (***before*** "doing the deed"), rather than the action itself (and its effect on the current situation). So that's one possible justification for the stylistic choice.

Comment: Fumble Fingers, how do you know it isn't 'future in the past'? I interpreted the sentence as implying that the work of Scottish foreign missions came after the period being discussed.

Comment: I think the same. I assume in this context "the period being discussed" is a loose reference to a time when some Scots were emigrating to "colonies of settlement" - and by implication, some *later* Scots went to India and Africa as missionaries. The first sentence of my answer was only supposed to be pointing out that the word ***in*** doesn't form part of the construction under consideration (which ***is*** "Future in the Past"). But if even you could misread it, my phrasing must be terrible - I'll reword it.

Comment: I beg your pardon. I interpreted your original answer as saying that the whole sentence wasn't 'future in the past'.

Comment: I'm glad you did! Sure - you might say the mistake was yours in that you didn't read my exact words very carefully, but the fact that it could happen *at all* is proof positive that my phrasing wasn't suitable for this site. Which I know is a failing of mine - I genuinely do admire others here (yourself included) when I see them saying the same thing as me, but using less and simpler words.

Answer (score 1):

When a writer describing historical events says that someone 'was to do' something, it means that they did it at a later time - in the past from our perspective, but in the future from the perspective of the time being discussed.

> G.F. Handel moved to London in 1712 and was to live there for the rest of his life.

See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303349/was-to-do-sth-v-would-do-sth).